# ¿Porque no puedo ejecutar el emulador de Android?

Tags: android, avd

Saludos.No puedo ejecutar el emulador de Android en Android Studio. Ya instalé HAXM y la API 14 para IceCreamSandwich 4.0 . El error que aparece es el de la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

> this AVD´s configuration is missing a kernel file!

**El problema regularmente es que no existe la imagen, pero también puede ser que la imagen este corrompida así que debes eliminarla y tienes que volver a instalar.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes entrar a la configuración de tu Android Virtual Device y la configuración te sugerira actualizar/instalar.

`Tools` > `Android` > `AVD Manager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El "ARM EABI v7a System Imagen` debe estar disponible. Instalarlo a través del gestor de Android SDK Manager, como te muestro en las siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instalalo en todas las versiones que necesites probar, aunque como recomendación, crearía una aplicación compatible con la `API 17` (Jelly Bean) hacia arriba.

Espero hacerte ayudado, si no coméntame para poder darte otra posible solución.

!!Suerte!!

Comment: Aun sigue el problema. Probé incluso con Genymotion y sigue igual. No termina de cargarse el emulador.

Comment: ¿Solo te falla abriendo esa versión o es en todas?